# Почему переменные kv файла не принимают self?

Tags: python, python-3.x, классы, kivy

Как переменная kv файла  может сослаться на переменную py файла, использую self?

Дело в том, что App присуще только классам, а self - только функциям.

Переменная kv файла принимает только app:

```
'''
MDFlatButton:
    id: flat
    text: app.gg
'''
class Test(MDApp):
    gg = '123'
```

Но мне нужно, чтобы работало вот так:

```
MDFlatButton:
    id: flat
    text: self.gg
class Test(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        gg = '123'
```

чтобы сослаться на переменную внутри функции, нужен self, который не приемлет kv.
Вопрос: как сделать чтобы это работало и не выдавало ошибку?

```
MDFlatButton:
    id: flat
    text: self.gg
```

Или как - нибудь по - другому, но чтобы кнопка `MDFlatButton` брала аргумент `text` из функции.

***Помогите(***

Answer (score 0):

в файле kv нужно писать не self а root

вот код который я написал только что и все работает, если у вас не будет работать попробуйте обновить kivymd:

```
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen

from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.button import MDRectangleFlatButton, MDFlatButton

KV = '''
Screen:
    id: flat
    MDFlatButton:
        text: root.gg
        halign: "center"
'''
class MainApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        gg = '123'
        screen = Screen()
        screen.add_widget(MDFlatButton())
        return screen


MainApp().run()
```

и вот только на python:

```
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen

from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.button import MDRectangleFlatButton, MDFlatButton

class MainApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        flat = '123'
        screen = Screen()
        screen.add_widget(MDFlatButton(text= flat))
        return screen


MainApp().run()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не работает. Ошибка: File "C:\Users\lolo\PycharmProjects\FindWord\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 695, in _apply_rule
     value, bound = create_handler(
   File "C:\Users\lolo\PycharmProjects\FindWord\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 245, in create_handler
     raise BuilderException(rule.ctx, rule.line,